# Attach variable to *ngFor angular 4

Tags: angular, variables, scope, ngfor

How do I attach a local variable to an `*ngFor` loop?

The following is working, but if my array `<listInstruction>` has more than 1 item, the loop will spawn two `.divTest`. Well that's logic, but `<myLocalVariable>` is the same in the both `.divTest`. I want two variables different scope  `myLocalVariable` in each `.divTest`.

```
<div *ngFor="let instruction of listInstruction; let i = index; let myLocalVariable=false">
  <div class="divTest" (click)="myLocalVariable=!myLocalVariable">Click here</div>
</div>
```

How can I do that ? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you say where myLocalVarible will come from? and what it will be used for? Will it always start as false? You are going to update some other element based on if its true or false?

Comment: myLocalVarible came from no where. I just need it in my loop. That's why I try to create a variable on each loop iteration; without success...

Answer (score 2):

I think its best practice to have myLocalVariable actually stored in the component, not in the template.

I would probably do something like this:

Component:

```
state;

ngOnInit() {
  state = { myLocalVariables: [] };
  for(var i = 0; i < listInstruction.length; i++){
     state.myLocalVariables.push(false);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let instruction of listInstruction; let i = index;">
  <div class="divTest"     (click)="state.myLocalVariables[i]=!state.myLocalVariables[i]">Click here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, good idea, not what I thinking initially, but it should work great ;). Thanks